# JAVA_OPTS environment variables leading to memory error

Tags: grails, windows-7, java-7

Error occurred during initialization of VM:

```
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

`JAVA_HOME` set `JDK` bin, `GRAILS_HOME` set Grails bin

I set `JAVA_OPTS= -Xmx 1024m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

**System: Core i3, RAM: 4 GB**

Comment: System Core i3 ,Ram 4gb

Comment: -Xmx756m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=756m i modified hen showing error
| Running Grails application
| Error Server failed to start: GC overhead limit exceeded (Use --stacktrace to
see the full trace)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are a few problem with your OPTS constraints. Try setting this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms256m  -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Also, it is recommended that you use `GRAILS_OPTS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS` since setting `JAVA_OPTS` will use the same variables for all other Java-based application like GGTS editor, any solr server or any other JVM.

While setting `GRAILS_OPTS` will only be used by Grails.